# How to export multiple objects/materials to Substance Painter?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, .fbx

So I created a spaceship in Blender, made out of 5 individual parts (i.e. individual meshes). And I UV unwrapped all of them. Then I exported it into fbx.

However, in Substance Painter, I only get a single texture set and all the UV maps are stacked on top of each other.

Hence, the question is how to properly format the Blender output to get several texture sets in Substance Painter?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to assign different materials in blender for each part of the mesh you want a different texture set.